# FB C# SDK GetTaskASYNC

Tags: facebook-c#-sdk

Did anyone have any examples for FB C#SDK for client.GetTaskAsync?

Any pointers towards that example would be great.

Vishnu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

checkout https://github.com/facebook-csharp-sdk/facebook-windows8-sample

```
private async void GraphApiAsyncDynamicExample()
{
    try
    {
        var fb = new FacebookClient("access_token");
        dynamic result = await fb.GetTaskAsync("me");

        // You can either access it this way, using the .
        dynamic id = result.id;
        dynamic name = result.name;

        // if dynamic you don't need to cast explicitly.
        ProfileName.Text = "Hi " + name;

        // or using the indexer
        dynamic firstName = result["first_name"];
        dynamic lastName = result["last_name"];

        // checking if property exist
        var localeExists = result.ContainsKey("locale");

        // you can also cast it to IDictionary<string,object> and then check
        var dictionary = (IDictionary<string, object>)result;
        localeExists = dictionary.ContainsKey("locale");
    }
    catch (FacebookApiException ex)
    {
        // handle error
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but i am unable to retrieve the email adress with it. Is there another method to retrieve email Information?